# Can't start test server on physical device

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

I installed calabash on a new machine, but tests that I ran on my old machine will not run.

As far as I can tell, both machines are set up the same way.  They pull the project from the same repository, which includes a Gemfile with calabash-cucumber version 0.18.0.  I set the same BUNDLE_ID, DEVICE_ENDPOINT, and DEVICE_TARGET values and use the same physical device.

When I try to run the tests in the console on the new machine, I get this:

```
$ bundle exec calabash-ios console
Running irb...
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
ArgumentError: Could not find a device with a UDID or name matching 'com.my.apps.bundle.id'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/device.rb:126:in `device_with_identifier'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/device.rb:160:in `detect_device'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop/core.rb:71:in `run_with_options'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/run_loop-2.1.1/lib/run_loop.rb:134:in `run'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:718:in `block in new_run_loop'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:716:in `times'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:716:in `new_run_loop'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:584:in `relaunch'
    from /Users/rjones/gambit/gemstubs/ruby/2.1.0/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.18.0/lib/calabash-cucumber/core.rb:943:in `start_test_server_in_background'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/rjones/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Does the bundle id in your app match what you have set in config? "com.my.apps.bundle.id" looks pretty generic but perhaps you just replaced it here...

Comment: Yes, I did replace it here.  But, it is formatted like com.company-name.app-name, which is nothing like the UDID for my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update to 0.19.0.

Can you also paste the *exact* command you are using to start the

```
irb(main):001:0> start_test_server_in_background
ArgumentError: Could not find a device with a UDID or name matching
'com.my.apps.bundle.id'
```

It looks like you set your DEVICE_TARGET to the bundle id?  If not, then you have found a bug.  It is possible that 0.18.0 is not compatible with run-loop 2.1.1.  Downgrade to run_loop 2.0.9 if you want to verify that this is the problem.

Comment: It looks like there is an incompatibility between calabash-cucumber 0.18.0 and run_loop 2.1.1.  I can run calabash 0.18.0 with run_loop 2.0.9 or calabash 0.19.0 with run_loop 2.1.1.  But, it fails when I run calabash 0.18.0 with run_loop 2.1.1.

Comment: You should updated to Calabash 0.19.0 or the most recent version available.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, when updating cucumber gem from version `1.3.19` to version `2.3.3`. I also run tests on physical devices

edit: Sorry, forgot to mention, that I updated `run_loop` too from version `2.0.6` to `2.1.3`

So the versions:

`run_loop (2.1.3)
calabash-cucumber (0.18.1)`

I guess these are the two that could affect this part, and `cucumber` was not involved

I found a solution, by setting the variable `DEVICE` instead of `DEVICE_TARGET`

For example:

`BUNDLE_ID=<bundle_id> DEVICE=<dev_udid> DEVICE_ENDPOINT=<dev_ip> cucumber`

Instead of

`BUNDLE_ID=<bundle_id> DEVICE_TARGET=<dev_udid> DEVICE_ENDPOINT=<dev_ip> cucumber`